# Can I deploy my iOS application to lower iOS version?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, ios12

I have Xcode 10.1.2 with latest iOS version available i.e. 12.2.
I recently updated my iPhone to iOS 13.2. Now, I need to deploy my application to my phone but I'm unable to do so because Xcode does not have support for iOS 13.2 (Which is running in my phone). I don't have time to update my macOS (which is approximately of 8.5GB) and then update my Xcode to Xcode 11 (which is approximately of 6GB). Is there any workaround for this issue?

I tried looking for down-grading my iPhone but came to know that Apple does not allow you to do so.

Comment: Find device support file at https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: Download device support file and paste 
  file  following path 
 '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'

Comment: After that restart xcode.

Comment: Xcode 11.2 runs under macOS 10.14.4 so you don't need 10.15.1.